# How do you add a legend of geometries in ggplot2?

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2

Let's say I've got a set of data and I want to add a legend to each geometry that I plot it with. For example:

```
x <- rnorm(100, 1)
qplot(x = x, y = 1:100, geom = c("point", "smooth"))
```

And it would look something like this:

[image]

Now, I want to add a legend so it would say something like:

```
Legend title
*   points [in black]
--- smoothed [in blue]
```

Where I specify the "Legend title", "points", and "smoothed" names.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to add extra information is with annotation rather than a legend.

(I know it's a toy example, but ggplot is being sensible by not including a legend when there is only one kind of point and one kind of line.  You could make a legend, but it will by default take up more space and ink than necessary and be more work.  When there is only one kind of point its meaning should be clear from labels on the x and y axes and from the general context of the graph.  Lacking other information, the reader will then infer that the line is the result of fitting some function to the points.  The only things they won't know are the specific function and the meaning of the grey error region. That can be a simple title, annotation, or text outside the plot.)

```
#Sample data in a dataframe since that works best with ggplot
set.seed(13013)
testdf <- data.frame(x <- rnorm(100, 1),y <- 1:100)
```

One option is a title:

```
ggplot(testdf , aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()+
   stat_smooth(method="loess")+
   xlab("buckshot hole distance(from sign edge)")+
   ylab("speed of car (mph)")+
   ggtitle("Individual Points fit with LOESS (± 1 SD)")
```

[image: sample ggplot with title]

Another option is an annotation layer.  Here I used the mean and max functions to guess a reasonable location for the text, but one could do a better job with real data and maybe use an argument like `size=3` to make the text size smaller.

```
ggplot(testdf , aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point()+
   stat_smooth(method="loess")+
   xlab("buckshot hole distance (from sign edge)")+
   ylab("speed of car (mph)")+
   annotate("text", x = max(testdf$x)-1, y = mean(testdf$y), 
   label = "LOESS fit with 68% CI region", colour="blue")
```

[image: sample ggplot with annotation]

Comment: Thank you for the workarounds. However, I do want a legend. It's pretty a basic request and I'm surprised a sophisticated package like ggplot2 can't handle it.

Answer (score 1):

A fast way to annotate a ggplot plot , is to use **geom_text**

```
x <- rnorm(100, 1)
y = 1:100
library(ggplot2)
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
bp <-  ggplot(data =dat,aes(x = x, y = y))+
       geom_point()+ geom_smooth(group=1)


bp  <- bp +geom_text(x = -1, y = 3, label = "*   points  ", parse=F)
bp  <- bp +geom_text(x = -1, y = -1, label = "--- smoothed   ", parse=F,color='blue')
bp
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. +1 as I can create a makeshift legend this way. I'll wait, see if anyone knows how to make a proper legend.